# What is the difference between a slice and an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, coercion

Why are both `&[u8]` and `&[u8; 3]` ok in this example?

```
fn main() {
    let x: &[u8] = &[1u8, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", x);

    let y: &[u8; 3] = &[1u8, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

> The fact that `&[T; n]` can coerce to `&[T]` is the aspect that makes them tolerable. [— Chris Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794371/155423)

Why can `&[T; n]` coerce to `&[T]`? In what other conditions does this coercion happen?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`[T; n]` is an array of length `n`, represented as `n` adjacent `T` instances.

`&[T; n]` is purely a reference to that array, represented as a thin pointer to the data.

`[T]` is a slice, an unsized type; it can only be used through some form of indirection.

`&[T]`, called a slice, is a sized type. It's a [*fat pointer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57754902/1175496), represented as a pointer to the first item and the length of the slice.

Arrays thus have their length known at compile time while slice lengths are a runtime matter. Arrays are second class citizens at present in Rust, as it is not possible to form array generics. There are manual implementations of the various traits for `[T; 0]`, `[T; 1]`, *&c.*, typically up to 32; because of this limitation, slices are much more generally useful. The fact that `&[T; n]` can coerce to `&[T]` is the aspect that makes them tolerable.

There is an implementation of `fmt::Debug` for `[T; 3]` where `T` implements `Debug`, and another for `&T` where `T` implements `fmt::Debug`, and so as `u8` implements `Debug`, `&[u8; 3]` also does.

> Why can `&[T; n]` coerce to `&[T]`? In Rust, when does coercion happen?

It will coerce when it needs to and at no other times. I can think of two cases:

1. where something expects a `&[T]` and you give it a `&[T; n]` it will coerce silently;
2. when you call `x.starts_with(…)` on a `[T; n]` it will observe that there is no such method on `[T; n]`, and so autoref comes into play and it tries `&[T; n]`, which doesn’t help, and then coercion come into play and it tries `&[T]`, which has a method called `starts_with`.

The snippet `[1, 2, 3].starts_with(&[1, 2])` demonstrates both.

Comment: Regarding coercion, I'm a little confused. For example, the Pattern trait is implemented for &[char]. I make a variable x = [' '] and try to use &x as a pattern (e.g. pass it to trim_matches on a String), but this results in compiler error. I can see the type of x is &[char, 1]. If I try to pass &x[..] it gets forced into &[char] and now the compiler finds the Pattern implementation. Is there something I'm missing or is this &[T; n] -> &[T] coercion not checked when looking for trait implementations?

Comment: What I say may not be completely correct, but it is my understanding: Generic implementations have a nasty habit of getting in the way of coercions, because they’re essentially ranked as more important than array-to-slice coercion. It sees that all types satisfying `FnMut(char) -> bool` implement the trait, and so stops there, trying to satisfy that trait bound rather than playing around with type coercions. With const generics, this could be resolved by manually providing a `[char; N]` and/or `&[char; N]` implementation (`impl<const N: usize>`). Whether it will be is another matter.

Answer (score 19):

> Why can `&[T; n]` coerce to `&[T]`?

The other answer explains why `&[T; n]` *should* coerce to `&[T]`, here I'll explain how the compiler works out that `&[T; n]` *can* coerce to `&[T]`.

There are [four possible coercions in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html):

1. Transitivity.

   - If `T` coerces to `U` and `U` coerces to `V`, then `T` coerces to `V`.
2. Pointer weakening:

   - removing mutability: `&mut T` → `&T` and `*mut T` → `*const T`
   - converting to raw pointer: `&mut T` → `*mut T` and `&T` → `*const T`
3. [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html):

   - If `T: Deref<Target = U>`, then `&T` coerces to `&U` via the `deref()` method
   - (Similarly, if `T: DerefMut`, then `&mut T` coerces to `&mut U` via `deref_mut()`)
4. [`Unsize` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html):

   - If `Ptr` is a "pointer type" (e.g. `&T`, `*mut T`, `Box`, `Rc` etc), and `T: Unsize<U>`, then `Ptr<T>` coerces to `Ptr<U>`.
   - The `Unsize` trait is automatically implemented for:

     - `[T; n]: Unsize<[T]>`
     - `T: Unsize<Trait>` where `T: Trait`
     - `struct Foo<…> { …, field: T }: Unsize< struct Foo<…> { …, field: U }>`, provided that `T: Unsize<U>` (and some more conditions to make the job easier for the compiler)
   - (Rust recognizes `Ptr<X>` as a "pointer type" if it implements [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html). The actual rule is stated as, “*if `T: CoerceUnsized<U>` then `T` coerces to `U`*”.)

The reason `&[T; n]` coerces to `&[T]` is rule 4: (a) the compiler generates the implementation `impl Unsize<[T]> for [T; n]` for every `[T; n]`, and (b) the reference `&X` is a pointer type. Using these, `&[T; n]` *can* coerce to `&[T]`.

Answer (score 10):

I created this picture according to the answers of kennytm and Chris Morgan. It describes the various concepts:

[image]

Comment: `n` does not exist in memory. For a slice, it’s in the fat pointer, but for an array or array reference, it exists only in the type, as `N`; it is all sorted out at compile time and does not appear at runtime at all.

Comment: This is otherwise a super helpful illustration! I wish more people used visual aids when explaining concepts.