# Why is Rust converting &[&u8; 2] into &[&u8]?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

How and why does Rust convert `&[&u8; 2]` to `&[&u8]` in this code? I thought originally it must be doing some kind of [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) shenanigans, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
struct Example<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    params: &'a [&'b u8],
}

fn main() {
    let a = 2u8;
    let b = 3u8;
    let x = &[&a, &b];
    let st = Example { params: x };
    println!(" Size of x: {} ", std::mem::size_of_val(&x));
    println!(" Size of &[&u8; 2]: {} ", std::mem::size_of::<&[&u8; 2]>());
    println!(" Size of Example: {} ", std::mem::size_of::<Example>());
}

// Console out:
// Size of x: 8
// Size of &[&u8; _]: 8
// Size of Example: 16
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=cd06f4c4bbe7afd03359b7fb27a0351f&version=undefined)

Comment: Can you explain why you say "but that doesn't seem to be the case"? Otherwise, the proposed duplicate seems to answer all of your questions.

Comment: Deref coercion may be a confusing mechanism. Calling it shenanigans sounds like you are underestimating it. :P

Comment: @Shepmaster I've looked into Slice, Array, Deref doesn't list the coercion. Where exactly is it listed?

Comment: @DanielFath The answer to the duplicate states this, verbatim: "1. where something expects a &[T] and you give it a &[T; n] it will coerce silently;"

Comment: @E_net4, assuming kennytm is right (and RustNomicon is correct), the right answer is Unsize coercion, *not* Deref coercion.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was looking for is [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html).

Based on [kennytm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794235/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-and-array) and assuming the [Rustnomicon is correct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html), `&[&T; n]` is coerced into `&[T]`, using [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html). The relevant parts:

> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> - Unsizing: T to U if T implements CoerceUnsized
>
> `CoerceUnsized<Pointer<U>> for Pointer<T> where T: Unsize<U>` is
>   implemented for all pointer types (including smart pointers like `Box`
>   and `Rc`). Unsize is only implemented automatically, and enables the
>   following transformations:
>
> - `[T; n]` => `[T]`
> - `T` => `Trait` where `T: Trait`