# Converting a reference of an array of u8 into a <Vec<u8>>

Tags: arrays, generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to make a function that takes `T: Into<Vec<u8>>`, but when I try to pass an array of `u8` to it, it doesn't compile even if `From<&'a [T]>>` is implemented by `Vec`:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<&[u8; 5]>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

Here is my code

```
fn is_hello<T: Into<Vec<u8>>>(s: T) {
    let bytes = b"hello".to_vec();
    assert_eq!(bytes, s.into());
}

fn main() {
    is_hello(b"hello");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `b"hello"` has type `&[u8; 5]`, which does not implement `Into<Vec<u8>>`. You need to pass a `&[u8]` slice in order for it to compile:

```
is_hello(&b"hello"[..]);
```

I recommend the following question for an explanation of the difference between a slice and an array: [What is the difference between Slice and Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794235/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-and-array).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are normally coerced to slice, but sometimes there's no implicit conversion.

There are some other ways to force a coercion:

```
b"hello" as &[u8]
b"hello".borrow()
```