# Why doesn't a nested reference to an array coerce to a slice?

Tags: rust, dereference, coercion

I read [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules/28552082#28552082) from beginning to end, but I still have a question about the coercion from array to slice.

Let us think about the following code:

```
let arr: &[i32; 5] = &&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// let arr: &[i32] = &&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // Error; expected slice, found reference
```

I would expect that `&&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` has the type, `&&&[i32; 5]` and dereferences to  `&&[i32; 5]` => `&[i32; 5]` => `&[i32; 5]` => `&[i32]`,
but the result is different from what I expected.

I tried to run the following code:

```
let arr: &&&[i32; 5] = &&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let n = arr.first().unwrap(); // 1
```

That's the correct code. The type of `arr` is coerced to `&&&[i32; 5]` => `&&[i32; 5]` => `&[i32; 5]` => `&[i32]` and matches to the first argument of `first` in slice, `&self`.

What's the condition that arrays coerce to slices? I don't understand the difference between the former and the latter code.

I also checked [the documentation in the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/69ee5a8a9787336f8635ec12ed0c6199a70505e0/src/librustc_typeck/check/method#method-lookup), and guess that the above question has something to do with the sentence cited below;

> However we sometimes do other adjustments and coercions along the way, in particular unsizing (e.g., converting from [T; n] to [T]).`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346583/155423 answer your question?

Comment: It's a bit different in that my question seems to be about transitive coercions, whereas @Shepmaster 's Q&A link is about DST coercion itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of coercion is intended to work, but not implemented.

[Arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) do not implement `Deref`, so the coercion `&[T; n] -> &[T]` is not a deref coercion and does not work in quite the same way as one. Instead, it's called an "unsized coercion" because it turns a sized type (`[T; n]`) into an unsized one (`[T]`).

That said, the [language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) (which is not normative and may be outdated, but bear with me) lists the possible coercions, including the following (emphasis added):

> - `T_1` to `T_3` where `T_1` coerces to `T_2` and `T_2` coerces to `T_3` (*transitive case*)
>
>   **Note that this is not fully supported yet.**
> - `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`.
> - TyCtor(`T`) to TyCtor(`U`), where TyCtor(`T`) is one of
>
>   - `&T`
>   - `&mut T`
>   - `*const T`
>   - `*mut T`
>   - `Box<T>`
>
>   and where `U` can be obtained from `T` by [unsized coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions).

The last bullet, unsized coercion, is what allows `&[T; n]` to coerce to `&[T]`. Notably, this only describes one layer of referencing; it doesn't cover the `&&[T; n]` -> `&[T]` case (for which we also need `Deref` coercion).

Back to your non-working example:

```
let arr: &[i32] = &&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

The intended coercion is `&&&[i32; 5]` -> `&[i32]`. We can work out how this coercion *ought* to work:

1. `&[i32; 5]` coerces to `&[i32]` by unsizing;
2. `&&[i32; 5]` coerces to `&[i32; 5]` by `Deref`;
3. therefore, `&&[i32; 5]` coerces to `&[i32]` by transitivity.
4. `&&&[i32; 5]` coerces to `&&[i32; 5]` by `Deref`;
5. therefore, `&&&[i32; 5]` coerces to `&[i32]` by transitivity.

But it doesn't. The quote above hints at why: under the transitive case, it says "Note that this is not fully supported yet". As far as I can tell, according to [issue #18602](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18602), "not fully supported" is a hedge; it would be more accurate to say "unimplemented". So, for now, **coercion via transitivity is not possible at all**. Apparently this issue is not a high priority, probably because sized arrays aren't very common. (I suspect this might become a more common complaint when const generics land, since that may make arrays more useful.)

So why *does* `arr.first()` work? Well, the ["auto-dereferencing rules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules?noredirect=1&lq=1) used to find methods invoked with the `.` (dot) operator are different from the coercion rules. Autoderef is similar to manually dereferencing any number of times until you get something (that can be coerced to a type) with the given method. This means you don't need transitive coercion to find method calls through autoderef.

---

#### Further reading

[RFC #401](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md) describes intended semantics of most coercions, but has never been fully implemented. [Issue #18602](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18602) tracks the status of transitive coercion.

The [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) also has a chapter on coercions and appears to agree with the reference book.

Comment: I see. The coercion in "auto-dereferencing rules" is counted as once, whereas the coercions in the code `let arr: &[i32] = &&&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` are more than once. The diffrerence between the two occurs because transitive coercions are still unimplemented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KentaNakajima Yep, pretty much. I'm slightly surprised this isn't a better known issue, given how useful coercions are. Although to be honest, I never really thought much about it; I guess that's true for most users.