# What is an example of implicit coercion transitivity?

Tags: rust, coercion

I read the following [in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html):

> Coercion is allowed between the following types:
>
> Transitivity: `T_1` to `T_3` where `T_1` coerces to `T_2` and `T_2` coerces to `T_3`.

I could not find an example which proves it. I can not think of two types that have no implicit coercion between them but there is a third type that has an implicit coercion between those two.

This is the first time I came across this great concept so I'd be glad to see a real example.

Comment: Is `&&&&&&&&T` -> `&U` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah, what does it mean? I'm lookin for a useful example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a nested reference to an array coerce to a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237733/why-doesnt-a-nested-reference-to-an-array-coerce-to-a-slice) tl;dr: it's not implemented.