# What is the difference between a slice and reference in Rust?

Tags: rust, reference, slice, terminology

I don't understand the difference between a slice and a reference. What is the difference between `&String` and `&str`? I read some stuff online that said a reference was a thin pointer and slice is a fat pointer, but I don't know and can't seem to find what those two mean. I know that a slice can coerce into a reference, but how does it do that? What is the `Deref` trait?

Comment: `I read some stuff online` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer-in-rust

Comment: I read it but I don't understand why a slice has unknown size at compile time for example &str.

Comment: Given a variable `x` of type `&str` - what size does it have? Compare it with variables of type `i8` (1 byte) or i128 (16 bytes) or a `struct Foo {x:i8,y:i128}` (1 byte + 16 bytes = 17 bytes, ignoring alignment). A variable of type `&Foo` will use the size of the pointer, dererencing will give you an object of size 17 bytes. Since the size of `str` or `[i8]` is variable, it has to be stored making a fat pointer out of the reference.

Comment: Commenting just to link to [What is the difference between a slice and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30794235/3650362)

Answer (score 33):

In Rust, a slice is a contiguous block of homogeneously typed data of varying length.

What does this mean?

- `[u8]` is a slice. In memory, this is a block of `u8`s. The slice itself *is* the data. Many times though, people refer to `&[u8]` as a slice. A `&[u8]` is a *reference to* that block of data. That reference contains two things: a pointer to the data itself, and the length of the data. Since it contains two things, it is therefore called a fat pointer. A `&u8` is also a reference (can also be thought of as a pointer **in this case** *****), but we already know that whatever it points to will be a single `u8`. Therefore, it is a thin pointer since it only has one element.

  You are guaranteed that *all* the data in a `[u8]` is of type `u8`.

  Since your `[u8]` is just defined as a contiguous block of memory of type `u8`, there's no compile time definition as to how large it is. Hence, we *need* to store its length in a pointer to it. We also can't put it on the stack (This translates to: we can't have a local variable that is just a `[u8]` ******).

Expanding:

- A `[T]` is a slice of `T`s. For any given `T`, as long as `T` is itself a sized type *******, we can imagine a type `[T]`.
- A `str` is a slice of a string. It is guaranteed to be valid UTF-8 text, and that's everything that separates it from a `[u8]`. Rust could have dumped the valid UTF-8 guarantee and just defined everything else in `str` as part of `[u8]`.

Well, since you can't own a slice locally ********, you might be wondering how we create slices.

The answer is that we put the data in something with the size already known, and *then* borrow slices from that.

Take for example:

```
let my_array: [u32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
```

We can slice `my_array` into a `[u32]` like so:

```
let my_slice: [u32] = my_array[..];
```

But by slicing we lose size information statically, and since local variables end up on the stack which requires a predetermined size, we must put it under a reference:

```
let my_slice: &[u32] = &my_array[..];
```

The point of a slice, is that it's a very flexible (barring lifetimes) method of working with contiguous blocks of data, no matter *where* the data comes from. I could've just as easily made `my_array` a `Vec<u8>`, which is heap-allocated, and it would still have worked.

> What is the difference between &String and &str?

`&String` is a reference to the whole string object. The string object in Rust is essentially a `Vec<u8>`. A `Vec` contains a pointer to the data it "contains", so your `&String` could be thought of as a `&&str`. And, that is why we could do either of the following:

```
let my_string: String = "Abc".to_string();

let my_str: &str = &my_string[..]; // As explained previously
// OR
let my_str: &str = &*my_string;
```

The explanation of this brings me to your last question:

> What is the deref trait?

The `Deref` trait, is a trait which describes the dereference (`*`) operator. As you saw above, I was able to do `*my_string`. That's because `String` implements `Deref`, which allows you to dereference the `String`. Similarly, I can dereference a `Vec<T>` into a `[T]`.

Note however, that the `Deref` trait is used in more places than just where `*` is used:

```
let my_string: String = "Abc".to_string();

let my_str: &str = &my_string;
```

If I try to assign a value of type `&T` into a place of type `&U`, then Rust will try to dereference my `T`, as many times as it takes to get a `U`, while still keeping at least one reference. Similarly, if I had a `&&&&....&&&&T`, and I tried to assign it to a `&&&&....&&&&U`, it would still work.

**This** is called deref coercion: automatically turning a `&T` into a `&U`, where some amount of `*T` would result in a `U`.

---

- *: Raw pointers `*const T` and `*mut T` are the same size as references, but are treated as opaque by the compiler. The compiler doesn't make any guarantees about what is behind a raw pointer, or even that they're correctly aligned. Hence, they are unsafe to dereference. But since the `Deref` trait defines a `deref` method which is safe, dereferencing a raw pointer is special, and will not be done automatically either.
- **: This includes other dynamically sized types too, such as trait objects, and `extern type`s. This also includes `struct`s which contain a dynamically sized type as their last member as well, although these are very difficult to correctly construct, but will become easier in the future with the `CoerceUnsized` trait. It is possible to invalidate all of this (Except for `extern type`s) with the use of the `unsized_locals` nightly feature which allows some use of dynamically sized locals.
- ***: Sized types are all types whose size is known at compile time. You can identify them generically; given a type `T`, `T`'s size is known at compile time if `T: Sized`. If `T: ?Sized`, then its size may not be known at compile time (`T: ?Sized` is the most flexible requirement for callers since it accepts *anything*). Since a slice requires the data inside to be contiguous, and homogenous in size and type, dynamically sized types (Or `!Sized`) aren't possible to contain within a slice, or an array, or a `Vec<T>`, and maintain `O(1)` indexing. While Rust could probably write special code for indexing into a group of dynamically sized types, it currently doesn't.
- ****: You actually *can* own a slice, it just has to be under a pointer which owns it. This can be, for example, a `Box<[T]>`, or a `Rc<[T]>`. These will deallocate the slice on their own (A `Box` when dropped, and a `Rc` when all strong and weak references of an `Rc` are dropped (The value's destructor is called when all strong references are dropped, but the memory isn't freed until all weak references are gone, too.)).

Comment: Quoting the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html): _Another data type that does not have ownership is the slice. Slices let you reference a contiguous sequence of elements in a collection rather than the whole collection._ So `[u8]` is not a slice, it's an unsized array; `&[u8]` is a slice.

Comment: The book is calling `&[T]` a slice because it is easier to understand for beginners, who are only new to the language. The [reference page for a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types/slice.html) states that _The slice type is written as `[T]`_, and [the documentation for a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) describes it as _A dynamically-sized view into a contiguous sequence, `[T]`_.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but this part is not fully clear: "_But since we can't own a local variable whose size isn't already known, we must put it under a reference_".  When you do `let my_slice: [u32] = my_array[..];`, `my_array` has a known size. I am also not sure that the verb "own" is appropriate in this case because of its special meaning in Rust. I don't think you're using it in the Rust sense here.

Comment: @nbro Fair enough, I've edited it to more precisely mean the point I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

### What is a reference

A reference is like a pointer from C (which represents a memory location), but references are never invalid* (i.e. null) and you can't do pointer arithmetic on references. Rust's references are pretty similar to C++'s references. One important motivating reason to use references is to avoid `move`ing or `clone`ing variables. Let's say you have a function that calculates the sum of a vector (note: this is a toy example, the right way to get the sum of a vector is `nums.iter().sum()`)

```rust
fn sum(nums: Vec<u32>) -> Option<u32> {
    if nums.len() == 0 {
        return None;
    }
    let mut sum = 0;
    for num in nums {
        sum += num;
    }
    Some(sum);
}
```

this function moves the vector, so it is unusable afterward.

```rust
let nums = vec!(1,2,3,4,5);
assert_eq!(sum(nums), 15);
assert_eq!(nums[0], 1); //<-- error, nums was moved when we calculated sum
```

the solution is to pass a reference to a vector

```rust
fn sum(nums: &Vec<u32>) -> Option<u32> {
...
}
```

```rust
let nums = vec!(1,2,3,4,5);
assert_eq!(sum(&nums), 15);
assert_eq!(nums[0], 1); // <-- it works!
```

### What is a slice

A slice is "a view into a [contiguous] block of memory represented as a pointer and a length." It can be thought of as a reference to an array (or array-like thing). Part of Rust's safety guarantee is ensuring you don't access elements past the end of your array. To accomplish this, slices are represented internally as a pointer and a length. This is fat compared to  pointers, which contain no length information. Similar to the sum example above, if `nums` were an array, rather than a `Vec`, you would pass a slice to `sum()`, rather than the array itself.

### String vs str

A `str` is an array of [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded characters, and an `&str` is a slice of utf-8 encoded characters. `String` is a `Vec` of utf-8 encoded characters, and `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`, which means that an `&String` behaves a lot like (coerces to) an `&str`. This is similar to how `&Vec<u32>` behaves like `&[u32]` (Vec implements `Deref<Target=[T]>`)

---

* unless made invalid with unsafe rust

Comment: P.S. to be clear, slices are also references. When you're generic over a type `T`, then `&T` is _definitely_ a reference, and it _might_ also be a slice.