# Why will Rust allow a specific array element in a println!, but not a slice

Tags: rust

If I try to compile this Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    // Create vector 
    let mut fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "cherry", "grape"];

    // Add element
    fruits.push("orange");  

    // Print
    println!("Fruit vector: {:?}", fruits[2]); 
}
```

There is no problem. But this Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    // Create vector 
    let mut fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "cherry", "grape"];

    // Add element
    fruits.push("orange");  

    // Print
    println!("Fruit vector: {:?}", fruits[2..3]); 
}
```

Does not compile. The reason for the error is given as:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[&str]` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:9:36
    |
9   |     println!("Fruit vector: {:?}", fruits[2..3]); 
    |                             ----   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |                             |
    |                             required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[&str]`
```

Why is this an issue for `fruits[2..3]`, but not `fruits[2]`?

Comment: A followup question: `println!("{:?}", x)` does not move `x`; the implementation of `println!` implicitly takes its arguments by reference to avoid having the author have to write `&` before each one. So why isn't a reference similarly added in `println!("{:?}", fruits[2..3])`?

Answer (score -1):

When you pass an argument to a function, it must be sized. Unsized values usually need to be referenced by something that is sized. Conveniently, references are sized.

The data inside `fruits[2]` has a size that is known at compile time. Fruits is a `Vec` of `&'static str` (in other words a dynamic array of string literals). Each of its items has the datatype `&str`. `&str` means a reference to a `str` (string). A reference has a known size at compile time, similar to how a pointer has a known size at compile time. That's why `fruits[2]` works in `println!`

We can agree that `fruits[2..3]` has a fixed size. Unfortunately, the data type of `fruits[2..3]` is the same as `fruits[2..4]`, so must be unsized. A slice could have 1 fruit, 10 fruits, 100 fruits... the compiler doesn't know how to deal with that data directly in the context of an argument. We need a way to pass dynamically sized data around. That's where references & slices come in.

What you're looking for is called a "slice", in other words, a reference that can refer to a contiguous chunk of memory (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html). Since a slice stores a known number and type of things (where your data is & how big it is), it has fixed size.

Long story short, you can make the value you pass to `println` Sized by getting a reference to your slice.

```rust
println!("Fruit vector: {:?}", &fruits[2..3]);
```

To be clear `fruits[2]` has type `&str`, but `fruits[2..3]` has type `[&str]` (Array of &str), even though that array only has one element, `fruits[2]`

Comment: _"the data type of `fruits[2..3]` is the same as the one used to represent an array"_ -- No, it's not. Arrays _are_ sized. This is a slice, which is `!Sized`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151916/3987475

Comment: `fruits[2..3]` is a slice and has type `[&str]`. For it to be a slice it should be `&[&str]`. Since we almost never use `fruits[2..3]` without the `&`, it's not really a slices,it  so maybe we can't call it an array since it's !Sized, but we can we really call it a slice since it's not a ref? 

*"In Rust, a slice is a contiguous block of homogeneously typed data of varying length."*
Maybe we can, in that case I misused the word array

Comment: Edit: I went ahead and updated my post to not misuse array. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -4):

Because `fruits[2..3]` returns a vector you can never print a vector but can only reference it:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Create vector 
    let mut fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "cherry", "grape"];

    // Add element
    fruits.push("orange");  

    // Print
    println!("Fruit slice: {:?}", &fruits[2..3]); 
}
```

Comment: It returns a slice, not a vector. The error occurs because slices don't have a size known at compile time, so you generally need to borrow them -- references to slices do have a known size.