# Why do arrays automatically convert themselves into slices?

Tags: arrays, rust, type-conversion, slice, borrow

In Rust, the slice type, `[T]`, has many useful methods, such as `.last()`.  However, equivalent methods are not present on the array type, `[T; N]`, yet it is still possible to call those slice methods from an array object.

For example:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let arr: [u32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let slice: &[u32] = &arr;

    // last() is a method of the (unsized) slice type, so this is fine
    println!("Slice len: {}", slice.last().unwrap());

    // This works, but how?
    println!("Array len: {}", arr.last().unwrap());
}
```

How does the array type automatically inherit the methods of the slice type?  Is it possible to do so for a custom type?

I suspect that it is something to do with `[T; N]` implementing `Borrow<[T]>`, but that doesn't answer the question of why we don't need to write `arr.borrow().last()` instead.

(Note: I am trying to implement my own dynamically sized type that wraps an slice and a few other fields, and I would like to make the equivalent type wrapping an array inherit methods from my dynamically sized type.)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346583/1021959) answers my question.